# How to display date format like “16 Mar,Monday” in iOS? 2

Tags: ios, xcode6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to display today date format like `16 Mar,Monday`,Here my code is

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMM, EEEE"];
 dateLabel.text = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

I am getting output is 16MAR,MONDAY ,But my output should be 16 Mar, Monday.Thanks

Comment: Is dateLabel a custom UILabel subclass that implements `setText:` and calls `super.text = [text uppercaseString];`? Your dateFormat yields the correct results.

Comment: Or maybe it uses a font that is uppercase only. The problem is most likely in with dateLabel

Comment: Yes,  i didn't observe my font displaying in uppercase format only ,i have changed the format  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM,EEEE"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date String %@",dateString);
```

I am getting same output that you want

[image]

Hope you will got success..

Comment: Which is funny, because it's the exact same code as in your question.